# How to use a single .class file in a java package?

Tags: java

I want to write a code like this

```
package mypackage;
public class A extends B {
}
```

But all that I have is the B.class file which is compiled from a single B.java file with no package specified.

Could anyone help me out?
Thanks!

I've tried putting `B.class` in my `./src` and `A.java` in `./src/mypackage` and run `javac -cp src ./src/package/A.java` but it wouldn't compile. It wouldn't compile neither if I put `B.class` in the same folder as `A.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. By your description, class `B` is in the default (unnamed) package. The Java language rules do not allow classes outside the default package to refer to classes in the default package.

The only way you can use this class is to put `A` in the default package as well. That is, move it one directory up, and remove the `package` statement.

Alternatively, you need to have the sources of class `B` (or decompile it), move it into a package and add a package statement, and recompile.

Comment: Or put class `B` in package `mypackage`, no?

Comment: So it's not possible to have a package hierarchy, I have to make every file flat in one folder?

Comment: @Abra I won't work if I don't delete the package declaration line.

Comment: @Abra The OP says they only have the compiled class of `B`, so they can't put `B` in `mypackage`.

Comment: @egrr You can have as many packages as you want, but you cannot reference classes that are in the default (unnamed) package. If you use packages, all classes you use must be in a named package. Also, it is important to understand that packages don't have a hierarchy as such. Each package is an individual namespace, even if they look hierarchical. For example, the package `java.util.stream` is not a member of the package `java.util`.

Comment: If class `B` is in the default package, and you have no way to recompile it so it is in a named package, then yes, you will need to put every class that uses `B` in the default package (and by extension, all classes that use those classes, and so on). On the other hand, classes in the default package can use classes in named packages.